# Using asorti function in shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sh

I dont know how to use asorti function in shell script language , i have tried the following commands :

```
n= gawk `asorti($array)`
n= awk `asorti(array)`
n= gawk `asorti($array)`
```

but none of them are work !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while calling function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149041/error-while-calling-function)

Comment: yeah , i'm ask this question , i will delete it . 
@ElliottFrisch

Comment: That's because `asorti` is for sorting awk arrays, not bash arrays. You can't just pick out cool functions from other languages and drop them into your shell script. Show us your code and tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @glennjackman , is there any similar function in shell ?

Comment: Edit your question: show your code and your array, and tell us what you want to do.

Comment: @glennjackman , i have an associative array and i need to sort it .

Comment: `shell != awk` just like `shell != C`. They are completely different tools/languages. asorti() is an awk function, just like fputs() is a C function. You would not expect to be able to call fputs() from shell.

Comment: as I wrote in my answer, you may want to read some manual for shell script programming or awk programming. Apart from the confusion of asorti(), there are still many mistakes in your script. space after `=`, awk/gawk as literal string, wrong usage of back-tick, awk expression, quotes are missing ... ..., I can hardly find some part in the codes which is correct. so start reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to display the sorted array, use `sort`: given

```
declare -A arr=( [foo]=bar [baz]=qux )
```

sort by array indices

```
for idx in "${!arr[@]}"; do echo "$idx:${arr[$idx]}"; done | sort -t: -k1,1
```

```
baz:qux
foo:bar
```

sort by array values

```
for idx in "${!arr[@]}"; do echo "$idx:${arr[$idx]}"; done | sort -t: -k2
```

```
foo:bar
baz:qux
```

Answer (score 1):

`asorti()` is a function of (g)awk, not a function of shell.

maybe you want to:

```
n=`awk '{...asorti(array)...print....}' input`
then use $n
```

read the awk man page please!

read some shell script manual please!